# Changing the Value of a paired item in a Map Data structure having a list of items as a value

Tags: c++

I could you some help. I have a unordered map data structure, where each map item (key) is a list of (node,value) pairs. see data structure below.

I am changing the value of a paired item in a list using an iterator, but it's not working.
I am wondering how I can get the value changed.

```
   typedef std::unordered_map< std::string, std::list< std::pair<std::string, int> > > di_Acyclic_Graph_Structure;
    di_Acyclic_Graph_Structure global_RT;
    global_RT["ialu"].push_back(std::make_pair("ialu1",1));
    global_RT["ialu"].push_back(std::make_pair("ialu2",1));

    adjNodesStructure adjNodes = global_RT["ialu"];
 

    for (auto iterator=adjNodes.begin(); iterator!=adjNodes.end(); iterator++)
    {
      if (whatever reason)
      {
       // changing the value of the second item of the 
       (*iterator).second = 2;
       // I expect the value of global["ialu"] -> which gives me a list ialu1, ialu2
       // I expect the value of ialu1 to become 2.
       // This is not working
       }
     }
```

Comment: With `adjNodesStructure adjNodes = global_RT["ialu"];` you make a *copy* of the list. Any modifications to that copy will not change the original. You probably want a *reference* instead.

Comment: `adjNodesStructure adjNodes = global_RT["ialu"];` -- C++ is not Java.  When you use `=`, you are making a copy -- you're not creating a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `=`, and the left-hand-side is not a reference, you are creating a copy of what's on the right side of the `=`.  Thus what is occurring is that you're working on a copy, and not the original item.

Unlike other popular computer languages such as Java, in C++, the `=` does not automatically use references.  If you are used to such languages like Java, C#, etc. this is where C++ becomes a totally different animal.

C++ is a value-based language, where usage of `=` will make a copy *unless you specifically want a reference*.

---

Thus, what you should be doing is to get a reference to the item you want to change.

To get a reference:

`adjNodesStructure& adjNodes = global_RT["ialu"];`

Note the usage of the declaration of the reference variable using `&`. Just that one character change in the line makes all the difference.

Comment: Should I also change from (*iterator).second = 2 to iterator->second =2 after doing adjNodesStructure& adjNodes = global_RT["ialu"]

Comment: That's just a matter of preference.  The compiled code will probably be exactly the same.